# Word to encompass object's location or size

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to encompass an object's x location, y location, width or height? Basically the word (if it exists) could mean either its location or size. It would probably have to be rather vague.

Comment: Could you give more context? an example sentence where the word would be found? Some guesses as to what you think might be a suitable word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wiktionary's sense 3 of *[geometry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/geometry)* is suitable:

> the spatial attributes of an object

That is the sense used in X Window System *geometry specifications*, which may specify width, height, x-offset, and y-offset, or may specify  width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "coordinates" might be a possible - at least with respect to position as noted by X, Y, and Z axes. Those are spatial. Height and width are dimensional.

On a side note, the machine used in the Dr Who series is called "TARDIS," which stands for "time and dimensions in space."

Comment: Time and *relative* dimension in space ;)

Comment: *Extent* might work, too.

Comment: I was thinking *extent* also, though it appears Jeff and I are both too lazy to make it a separate answer, especially since this one is already accepted.

Answer (score 1):

They are in the category of "Layout" of Microsoft Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a word that can mean both. I would use 'position' or 'location' for an object's coordinates, and 'dimensions' for height, length, width. The logical problem with combining those 2 properties into a single word is that a location is a point (zero dimensions), whereas the size is at least 1-dimensional (for lengths), up to 3-dimensional for bodies.